# PDF attachment corrupted

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pdf-generation, urlfetch

After the issue with GmailApp declaratrion has benn resolved, I'm stuck now with a new problem, regarding my pdf attachment which is unreadable.

Prior to this [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70283882/exception-the-parameters-string-string-string-class-class-dont-match-the/70283935?noredirect=1#comment124247323_70283935), the pdf attachment was working perfectly.

I'm doubting that the var "blobresponse" or "pdfOpts" are the source of the problem, but maybe I'm wrong.

What's going wrong with the script ? Could you please explain me ?
Here is a reproducible [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v9SNIwjl0p519aw0mL2RMOnXlAdelrIyJkmeDi7BmR0/edit?usp=sharing)

```
function emailAsPDF() {

 SpreadsheetApp.flush();
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Recherche"));
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 var gid = sheet.getSheetId();
 var pdfOpts = 
    'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'+ // export as pdf
    '&size=0' + // paper size letter / You can use A4 or legal
    '&portrait=false' + // orientation portal, use false for landscape
    '&fitw=true' + // fit to page width false, to get the actual size
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=true' + // hide optional headers and footers
    '&pagenumbers=true&gridlines=false' + // hide page numbers and gridlines
    '&horizontal_alignment=CENTER&vertical_alignment=CENTER' +
    '&fzr=true' + // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    '&attachment=false' +
    gid;
// '&size=0&fzr=true&portrait=false&fitw=true&gridlines=false&printtitle=true&sheetnames=false&pagenumbers=true&attachment=false&gid='+gid;
 
 
 SourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var SourceSheet = SourceSS.getSheetByName("Recherche");
 var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + SourceSS.getId().replace(/edit$/, '') + '/export?exportformat=pdf&format=pdf' + pdfOpts;
 //var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'.replace(/edit$/, '') + '/export?exportformat=pdf&format=pdf' + pdfOpts;
 var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
 //var options = {
      
//options = {muteHttpExceptions: true};
 //var options = {
  var blobresponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token,
      },
      muteHttpExceptions: true}
    );
  //options);
  var CandidateName = ss.getRangeByName("Nom.Candidat").getValue();
  var blob=blobresponse.getBlob().setName(ss.getName() + " - " + CandidateName +".pdf" );
  var emailAddress = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var signature = Gmail.Users.Settings.SendAs.get("me", emailAddress).signature; 
  var mess = "Voulez-vous envoyer votre rapport  à l'adresse : " + emailAddress;
  var ans= Browser.msgBox("Courriel", mess, Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
  if (ans===Browser.Buttons.NO){return;}
  var mess="Votre rapport a été envoyé à l'adresse : " + emailAddress;
  //var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Recherche");
  var data = ss.getSheetByName("Données");
  const corps = data.getRange("A24:E27").getValues();
  const htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("HtmlSigTemplate");
  htmlTemplate.corps = corps;
  var emailSubject = "Vérifications pré-emploi complétées" +" - "+ CandidateName;
  const htmlForEmail = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent() + "--" + "<br>" + signature;
  //console.log(htmlForEmail);
  GmailApp.sendEmail(
    emailAddress, 
    emailSubject, 
    corps,
    {htmlBody: htmlForEmail,
    attachments:[blob]});
  Browser.msgBox("Courriel", mess, Browser.Buttons.OK); 
}


function parentFolder() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()); 
  var ParentFolder= file.getParents();
  while ( ParentFolder.hasNext() ) {
    var folder = ParentFolder.next();
    folderID=folder.getId();
     Logger.log(folderID);
  }
  return folderID;
}
```

Comment: For us to test your code, kindly include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (Dummy spreadsheet) in your post above. Also, what do you mean by unreadable? Could you show us what the file look like?

Comment: Here is a reproducible example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v9SNIwjl0p519aw0mL2RMOnXlAdelrIyJkmeDi7BmR0/edit?usp=sharing
Screenshot: https://pasteboard.co/ZFtxC9w7CoXH.png

Comment: Unable to access the spreadsheet and the message in screenshot is not in English. Try to use the browser settings to translate the drive message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the culprit after a long and painful research. You notice that the last line in the variable **pdfOpts** was missing a little detail

Old code:

```
var pdfOpts = 
    'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'+ // export as pdf
    '&size=0' + // paper size letter / You can use A4 or legal
    '&portrait=false' + // orientation portal, use false for landscape
    '&fitw=true' + // fit to page width false, to get the actual size
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=true' + // hide optional headers and footers
    '&pagenumbers=true&gridlines=false' + // hide page numbers and gridlines
    '&horizontal_alignment=CENTER&vertical_alignment=CENTER' +
    '&fzr=true' + // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    '&attachment=false' +
    gid;
```

New code:

```
  const pdfOpts = '&top_margin=0.30&bottom_margin=0.30&left_margin=0.25&right_margin=0.25'
    +'&size=LETTER' // paper size letter / You can use A4 or legal
    +'&portrait=false' // orientation portal, use false for landscape
    +'&fitw=true' // fit to page width false, to get the actual size
    +'&sheetnames=false' // hide optional headers
    +'&printtitle=true' //and footers
    +'&pagenumbers=true' // hide page numbers 
    +'&gridlines=false' //and gridlines
    +'&horizontal_alignment=CENTER'
    +'&vertical_alignment=CENTER'
    +'&fzr=true' // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    +'&attachment=false'
    +'&gid='+gid;
```

Comment: It's good that you spotted the issue, but it would alos be good it you outlined the details that are new. Along those lines, the details don't look so relatively 'little'. Several assignments are different, and there are a few completely new fields.

Answer (score 0):

The code has several issues. I suggest you to start to cleaning up your script by removing the redundant statements and adopting better modern JavaScript practices. I.E.

Instead of `var` use `const` or `let`. Old Google Apps Script code used `var` all the time because `const` and `let` were not supported. The current Google Apps Script default runtime does it.

Related

- [What's the difference between using "let" and "var"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/762011/1595451)
- [v8 JavaScript performance implications of const, let, and var?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40070631/1595451)

Instead of

```
ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Recherche"));
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
```

use

```
 const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Recherche");
```

Instead of

```
SourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var SourceSheet = SourceSS.getSheetByName("Recherche");
 var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + SourceSS.getId().replace(/edit$/, '') + '/export?exportformat=pdf&format=pdf' + pdfOpts;
```

use

```
const url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + ss.getId() + '/export?exportformat=pdf&format=pdf' + pdfOpts;
```

NOTES:

1. `getId()` returns the spreadsheet id, it doesn't includes `edit`.
2. It not necessary to declared new variables for the spreadsheet and sheet to be exported as PDF as the ones that were previously declared have the required objects.

Also you might find helpful to review previous questions related to the use of `UrlFetchApp` to create a PDF like the following:

- [Generate PDF of only one sheet of my spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49197358/1595451)
- [Exporting Google Sheet as PDF with Custom Headers or Footers in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50025746/1595451)
- [Can no longer produce PDF from Google Sheets spreadsheet for some of the users](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63413712/1595451)